# SQL based data diff: longest common subsequence

Tags: sql, algorithm, diff

I'm looking for research papers or writings in applying [Longest Common Subsquence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm to SQL tables for obtaining a data diff view. Other sugestions on how to resolve a table diff problem are also welcomed. The challenge being that SQL tables have this nasty habit of geting rather BIG and applying straightforward algorithms designed for text processing may result in a program that never ends...

so given a table `Original`:

```
Key  Content
1    This row is unchanged
2    This row is outdated
3    This row is wrong
4    This row is fine as it is
```

and the table `New`:

```
Key Content
1   This row was added
2   This row is unchanged
3   This row is right
4   This row is fine as it is
5   This row contains important additions
```

I need to find out the `Diff`:

```
+++ 1 This row was added
--- 2 This row is outdated
--- 3 This row is wrong
+++ 3 This row is right
+++ 5 This row contains important additions
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Key` imposes an order on the rows, otherwise terms like 'sequence' and 'subsequence' would make no sense on an unordered set (like a relational table).

Comment: Don't forget that tables do not, in theory, have any order to the rows - which also complicates things.  You have to define an order for the table comparisons.

Comment: I don't think this is any different from the usual problem: the best you can do is O(n^2) (ignoring time to compare table rows) where n is the number of rows. If you know that no row moves by more than k positions, you can do it in O(nk) by modifying the usual dynamic programming algorithm. You'll probably have to assume something like this, with some reasonably small k, if n^2 is too large.

Comment: That makes me wonder what algorithm inbuilt tablediff utility uses ? Anyone ?

Answer (score 1):

If you export your tabls into csv files, you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvdiff/

Quote:
csvdiff is a Perl script to diff/compare two csv files with the
possibility to select the separator. Differences will be shown like:
"Column XYZ in record 999" is different. After this, the actual and the
expected result for this column will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too simple for what you're after, and it's not research :-), but just conceptual.  I imagine you're looking to compare different methods for processing overhead (?).

--This is half of what you don't want ( A )

```
SELECT o.Key FROM tbl_ORIGINAL o INNER JOIN tbl_NEW n WHERE o.Content = n.Content
```

--This is the other half of what you don't want ( B )

```
SELECT n.Key FROM tbl_ORIGINAL o INNER JOIN tbl_NEW n WHERE o.Content = n.Content
```

--This is half of what you DO want ( C )

```
SELECT '+++' as diff, n.key, Content FROM tbl_New n WHERE n.KEY NOT IN( B )
```

--This is the other half of what you DO want ( D )

```
SELECT '---' as diff, o.key, Content FROM tbl_Original o WHERE o.Key NOT IN ( A )
```

--Combining C & D

```
( C )
Union
( D )
Order By diff, key
```

Improvements...

- try creating indexed views of the
  base tables first
- try reducing the length of the
  content field to it's min for
  uniqueness (trial/error), and then
  use that shorter result to do your
  comparisons

-- e.g. to get min length (1000 is arbitrary -- just need an exit)

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1
While i < 1000 and Exists (
Select Count(key), Left(content,@i) From Table Having Count(key) > 1 )
BEGIN
   i = @i + 1
END
```